# using model value in MVC codescope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-sharer

I am trying to get a model value in MVC codescope-

```
@model FunRanger.Models.CardModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CardDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var link = string.Format(
    "'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+'http://funranger.com/Home/CardDetails/?cardID'+'@Model.cardID",
    Url.Encode("http://funranger.com/Home/CardDetails/?cardID=@Model.cardID/"),
    Url.Encode("This is my site")
);

}
```

Here you can see that I am trying to get model value in `var link` and sharing it on facebook. 
Here in this codescope I want to get `@Model.cardID`'s value.

How do I get this model value?

For example URL would be like- `http://funranger.com/Home/CardDetails/?cardID=178`

**Edit-**

```
 string encodedUrl = String.Format("http://funranger.com/Home/CardDetails/?cardID={0}", Model.cardID);
    string link = string.Format("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={0}", Url.Encode(encodedUrl));
```

It is shared on my website with `encodeUrl` path.

Facebook sharing shows this-

[image]

It seems to be sharing an Image.

I am sharing it as below-

```
 <a href="@link">share in facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example URL would be like-
>   http://funranger.com/Home/CardDetails/?cardID=178

you can get it like this -

```
@{
    string encodedUrl = String.Format("http://funranger.com/Home/CardDetails/?cardID={0}/",Model.cardId);
    string link = string.Format("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={0}", Url.Encode(encodedUrl));
}
```

Output -

[image]

Between I am confused with your usage of String.Format(), you have not mentioned placeholders any where in your String.Format() implmentation.

Also I am not sure about `Url.Encode("This is my site")`

Comment: I was able to share it on my website with that `encodeUrl` path. But it doesn't seem to work on facebook still. It's an empty page sharing only.

Comment: @user3163213, I think you need to have proper Meta Description and Images on page, so that they will be used by FaceBook Sharer. Anyways I think your present problem got nothing to do with present question. I think you present question of getting Model Data into a link is solved.

Comment: @user3163213, I think for FB share question, you can start a altogether a new question in SO (first try to do some research and if you are not able to solve it then post the question).

Answer (score 0):

You Are appending the Model.cardId in wrong way. I am not sure what is the use of the other two arguments in the string.Format in y our case. Any way you need to append the value in  these ways.

```
1. var link = "http://funranger.com/Home/CardDetails/?cardID=" + Model.cardID;
2. var link = string.Format("http://funranger.com/Home/CardDetails/?cardID={0}",Model.cardID);
```